# Automating the WHERE filters on a SQL query

Tags: sql, excel

I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question.

I have a SQL query written for a project.

I am going to be given an Excel file with different criteria per row to filter the query on.

Is there any way that I can set up a query to run once for each row, applying the filter criteria in the `WHERE` statements (and commenting out those that are not used in a particular row)?

Just looking for a way to not have to manually run the query a couple of hundred times.

Comment: What tool will actually be executing the query?  Are you also doing that with Excel?

Comment: I figured I would need to use one of the tools at my disposal, so: Excel, R, or Python

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? How is a given criterion associated with a particular row?

Comment: In Excel you can use *VBA* that has enough features to execute a query. But question is why do you want to run a query multiple times? or actually what is that query, an Update, Insert or ...? - I can think about running one query instead. So please add more details in your question. - HTH ;).